# Let $W=\operatorname{Span}\{v_1 , ... , v_p\}$ where $v_1 , ... , v_p$ are in a vector space V. Show that $v_k$ is in W for $1\leq k \leq p$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let W be the set of all linear combinations of $v_1...v_p$ and let $v_k$ be some vector such that $1\leq k \leq p$, then:

$W=c_1v_1 + ... + c_pv_p$

when $c_1 , ..., c_p=0$ such that $c_k=1$ we get that :

$(0)v_1 + ... + (0)v_p=(1)v_k$

Thus $v_k$ is in W

Did I correctly show that $v_k$ is in $W$?

Comment: Except if $c_k=1$, $c_k v_k$ is not equal to $v_k$. Also have in mind that $W=c_kv_k$ is problematic to write. $W$ is a set and $v_k$ an element of that set.

Comment: $$W=Span\{v_1,...,v_p\}=\{c_1v_1+...+c_pv_p:c_1,...c_p\in \mathbb{F}\}$$ so taking $$c_1,...,c_{k-1},c_{k+1},...,c_p=0, c_k=1$$ shows $v_k\in W$

Comment: What do you want to demonstrate? $v_k\in W$ for any $1\leq k\leq p$? But let $k$ fixed and arbitrary, we have $v_k=1\cdot v_k$ then Then it is already a linear combination of $\{v_1,\dots,v_p\}$ and therefore $v_k\in W$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I fixed my answer.

Comment: You are still writing a set $W$ equal to a vector; you need the $\{\dots\}$ set-builder notation.